# not able to set a cookie using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I am trying to set a cookie using the following code using jquery and qtip.  As you can see, when this 'beforeShow' event is triggered I need to set a cookie.  I can confirm the event is being triggered as I see the alert although I'm not able to see the cookie being set?  Should this code work or am I missing something?
Many thanks,

```
        api: {
            beforeShow: function() {
                if(document.getElementById('CheckMessage')) {
                    alert("");
                    $.cookie("MyTestExampleCookie", "1");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: its just a simple cookie to know whether this event has been fired or not so that we can avoid the popup being shown again after the cookie has been set.  Can I do it without a plugin?

Comment: You can in raw javascript but jQuery does not have cookie manipulation built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.cookie = ("MyTestExampleCookie=1");
```

though it's more advisable to use some cookie lib

Answer (score 3):

Did you install jQuery cookie?

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I haven't, although I'm hoping to use native jquery functionality as it's only a simple state check that the event has been triggered..

Comment: @JamesRadford JQuery does not have cookie built in! look at the docs.

Comment: @JamesRadford $.cookie is certainly from the jQuery cookie library. It's not a heavy library and I recommend using this one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cookie unless you need to remember the value after the user has navigated away from the page. If you just want to know if a particular event has been triggered, set a normal variable.

If you do need to use cookies and manipulate these client-side, it is easier with a plugin as suggested above (but not absolutely necessary).

Comment: correct, the user can navigate away, hence the need for a cookie

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery, second answer for a non-plugin solution. Its not particularly clean imo.

Comment: im using this code although I can't see the cookie being set?  document.cookie = 'MyTestCookie=Agreed; expires=; path=/'

Comment: I'm using the WebDeveloper addon for Firefox and using the view cookie information toolbar option.  can see plenty of cookies, just not MyTestCookie